# Is the distributive property met in UML?

Tags: uml

So...basically i have this doubt:
Lets say we have 3 classes: a,b,c. 
If class A is related to B, and class B is related to class C, can we say that there is a logical relationship between A and C?
Lets make an example: in this picture i just made, we see class Police, class People and class Alarm. 
[image: UML]

So...If I wanted to say that both a policeman and a person can turn on the alarm when there is danger, would this representation be correct? As the Police class is attached to the alarm class through the class People, can the policeman generate an alarm? Or would it be necessary to join the police class with the alarm class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an operation in `Police` like `generatePeopleAlarm` that get a `People` and then calls on `People` an operation linke `turnOnAlarm`.

But how `Police` or `People` are informed that there is a danger ? And `Police` could be or not link to a list of `People`, how `Police` knows which `People` is linked to the alarm that has to be turned on ?

What's happens if `Police` is not linked with any `People` instance, it can not turn an alarm on ...

It would be more efficient to use the observer pattern. see [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). The alarm is the subject and `People` and `Police` are observers.